# How can I prevent a form reset from clearing my <input type="text"> element?

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, reset

If I put a form control on the page with a `value` already set, triggering the containing form's reset functionality will return the value to the original value at the time when the page was loaded.

However, if I create a form control using javascript, and append it to the DOM, the form control will be erased and made blank when the form is reset. How can I prevent this behavior? I would like to give the input a default value, so it will be treated the same way as a control that was on the page at page load.

In the following example, clicking RESET clears one input (the script-added one), but not the other (the static one). What I want is for both inputs to retain their value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.sourceforge.net/" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="container">
            <input type="reset" value="RESET" />
            <input type="text" value="DefaultValue" />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('value', 'DefaultValue2');
            document.getElementById('container').appendChild(input);
        };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Though I have not included jQuery in this simple test case, my project uses jQuery, and I would be happy for a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The form `reset()` uses the `defaultValue` property, so all you need to do is set that...

```
window.onload = function() { 
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.value = input.defaultValue = 'DefaultValue2';
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(input); 
};
```

Comment: Sadly this also changes the value property - I want the reset button to set the field to empty, but the initial value attribute on the field is set to some text.

Answer (score 0):

Forms have an `onreset` event, which, according to [ppk](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/submit.html) is available cross-browser. If the Javascript created element isn't reset to its initial value when the reset button is pressed, you could use the event to reset it "manually".

However, by my [testing](http://jsfiddle.net/CF85m/) resetting a javascript created element (I'm using Prototype in my example but it shouldn't make a difference) works in Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 5 without needed an additional `onreset` handler (but not in IE6).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add more functionality to the default 'reset' input, for example you could use the `onReset` event to set `input's value = 'defaultvalue2'`. This would reset both input fields, one statically and the other via the onReset method.